# enzyme shallow rendering just one node in redux components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, enzyme

Enzyme shallow rendering behaves in an unexpected way if I am rendering a redux component with a mocked store.

I have a simple test that looks like this :

```
  import React from 'react';
  import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
  import { createMockStore } from 'redux-test-utils';

  import Test from './Test'

  it('should render ', () => {
    const testState = {
      app: {
        bar: ['a', 'b', 'c']
      }
    };

    const store = createMockStore(testState)
    const context = {
      store,
    };
    const shallowComponent = shallow(<Test items={[]}/>, {context});

    console.log(shallowComponent.debug());

  }
```

The Test component looks like :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="here"/>
    )
  }
}
export default Test;
```

Which as expected prints out this :

```
 <div className="here" />
```

However if my component is a redux component :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="here"/>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    barData: state.app.bar
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Test)
```

Then what I get in the console is this :

```
<BarSeriesListTest items={{...}} barData={{...}} dispatch={[Function]} />
```

Why is there this difference? How do I test that my component has `<div className="here"/>` embedded in it in my redux version of the component?

Comment: This might help you https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1534 .

Scroll down and you will see a comment with lots of +

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing the HOC that `connect` is returning and not the component that you want to test.

You should use enzyme's [dive](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) function which will render the child component and return it as a wrapper.

`const shallowComponent = shallow(<Test items={[]}/>, {context}).dive();`

You can use it multiple times if you have multiple components that you need to dive through to get to. It's better than using `mount` as well because we are still testing in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

You should export the unconnected component and test it separately (notice the first `export`):

```
export class Test extends React.Component {

}
...
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Test)
```

While in your test you should test the rendering of the unconnected component like so (notice the curly braces around `{ Test }`):

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import { Test } from './Test';

describe('...', () => {
  it('...', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Test />)
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  })
})
```

Hope this helps.

Mode specifically for your described case the component should be:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="here"/>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    barData: state.app.bar
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Test)
```

The test spec should be:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import { Test } from 'Test';

describe('Test component', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Test />);
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Which generates the following snapshot:

```
exports[`Test component renders 1`] = `
<div
  className="here"
/>
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting the connected component by default. What you can do is import the component that is not connected to redux.

```
import { Test } from './Test';
```

Then your test should work.